# How to set background colour for all columns in a row using Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using `openpyxl` in one of my python applications for generating an excel file. Everything is working fine except the background color settings for a row. I need to set the same background color for all the columns in a row. Currently, I am using the following code to set the color for a cell. Now I would like to know how can I specify all the columns there in the columns section so that the color will be applied to all columns.

```
worksheet.cell(row=10, column=1).fill = PatternFill(start_color='D6BFD4',
                                                        end_color='D6BFD4',
                                                        fill_type="solid")
```

I need the same background for all the columns like 1,2,3 etc like the following image.

[image]

Comment: The openpyxl docs tell you that you have to format **all** cells individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given here is a sample for how to color a full row based on your code above. It will set the color to all the columns for row=10. You can change the color and row number to suit your needs. Do note that it will set the color till the column where data is present (equivalent to `ws.max_column`).

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

file = 'input.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename=file)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
clr_background = PatternFill(start_color='D6BFD4', end_color='D6BFD4', fill_type="solid")

# Enumerate the cells in the tenth row
for cell in ws["10:10"]:
    cell.fill = clr_background

wb.save(filename=file)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Please refer to this [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells) for accessing multiple cells. The above code will color cells from column 1 to last column with data. If you want to change it, you will need to replace the `for` loop like this...
Note: If you set F10 to XFD10, it will color till the last column in excel (not tested and hoping you don't need it)

```
for row in ws["A10":"F10"]: ##This will give you a cell range
    for cell in row:
        cell.fill = clr_background
```

**Ouput excel**

[image]

Comment: But actually, I only have value in the first column. So when I iterate through the loop, I am only getting A10, which has a value and color not applied to the first column. IS there any workaround that I can color other columns also?

Comment: Updated so that you can set a range (say A10-F10) with the color. Does this work? If you need it for the whole row, XFD10 is the last column, but I have not tested it.